# What is the meaning of 根拠となる土台?

Tags: meaning, translation, sentence

The 概説 for the word 奉仕 on Wikipedia  reads the following

> 往々にしてその根拠となる土台には宗教的な信念や、宗教的な意味合いの神奉仕[1]の形として、神ではないもののその代わりとしての、困難な場面におかれている隣人に手を差し伸べ、できる限りの援助を与えるというケースがある

Which I understood as: often 奉仕 is used to mean helping other who are in apredicament or need as a form of religious  ministration instead of God . I however don't understand this "根拠となる土台" .

Comment: Did you intend to include 根 in the portion you clipped out and just made a mistake in copy/pasting it, or did you overlook that it's 根拠?

Comment: The former , I edited

Comment: Should be good now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit redundant, but 根拠となる土台 itself means literally *the base that becomes/works as the grounds (for doing 奉仕)*.

Personally, it seems to be a bit odd sentence to start a paragraph with, but I suppose the whole structure parses as

- 往々にして（その根拠となる土台には....与える）というケースがある
- There are often cases where the base for doing service is to give help...

---

It should be a miswriting in the sense that 土台には does not connect with 与える very well.

Another possibility is to try to connect 土台には with ケースがある, but to me, it doesn't sound right either.

Comment: Right , 根拠となる土台には is unnaturally connected to threst of the sentence at leat form my understanding . Does 宗教的な信念や、宗教的な意味合いの神奉仕の形として、神ではないもののその代わりとして here mean that it has religious contation/bases where the emphasis is on minstrating people instead of ministrating god?

Comment: I think it is another miswriting. 神ではないもののその代わりとしての is difficult to fit in. But, what the sentence tries to say seems something like *There are cases where the base for doing service is, as a form of religious belief or ministration to god, (the will to) help other people in difficulties instead of god.* There should be several elements missing, e.g. 土台には...援助を与える**気持ち/意志がある**.

Comment: It almost looks like 隣人 could be a substitute for 神. On top of all that, it’s hard to tell whether 宗教的な信念 is paired with 神奉仕 or ケース. It’s awful writing.